# 404 error, using backing button to navigate single page: window.history.pushState and window.onpopstate

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller, umbraco

I am currently using Html5's window.history.pushState and window.onpopstate to hijack the brower's back button to enable back and forward browser navigation of content on a single html page called _ShoppingCart.cshtml. The website is using umbraco with an Mvc C# backend. Everything works correctly as long as the navigation is taking place on _ShoppingCart.cshtml (where the window.history.pushState and window.onpopstate is implemented); however if the user navigates away from _ShoppingCart.cshtml page and attempts to use the back or forward button to navigate to one of the urls added using window.history.pushState (i.e cart/shipping or cart/reviewPay) a 404 (page not found) error is thrown because there is no actual cart/shipping or cart/reviewPay page.

I would like to somehow redirect the cart/shipping or cart/reviewPay urls to _ShoppingCart.cshtml. Is there anyway to do this? Thank you for your help.

I am using this https://jsfiddle.net/fJ9wq/ as an example:

```
var setCurrentPage = function(url) {
   $('h2 span').html(url || "/");
    $("#menu-nav a[href='" + url + "']").fadeTo(500, 0.3);
};

$('#menu-nav a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href'),
        targetTitle = $(this).attr('title');


    $("#menu-nav a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").fadeTo(500, 1.0);


    window.history.pushState({url: "" + targetUrl + ""}, targetTitle, targetUrl);
   setCurrentPage(targetUrl);
});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    $("#menu-nav a").fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
        console.log(e);
    setCurrentPage(e.state ? e.state.url : null);
};
```

Comment: Do you use the /cart/shipping/ url at all in your application (e.g. does it call anything on that path), other than for display purposes?

Comment: No, it is only used for display purposes. There is no actual page.